# How to sync contacts with my app in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

How to sync Contacts in my Flutter App?
Like WhatsApp, Facebook does, I want to list all users from contacts who already have account in my app and if a new user is added to contacts list, the sync should also work. Hope to get solved with the exact method.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`contacts_service`](https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service) package to retrieve the contacts on your user's device. This package allows you to retrieve contacts on their device as a `Contact` object.

To sync these contacts, you should perform an operation on app startup that compares your current list of contacts to one that you retrieved with this package. Specifics would depend on your method of storing these contacts.